# c++ template expected primary expression before

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to templates and couldn't find the answer to my problem on the forums here, maybe I just don't know what to search for exactly.

My code:

```
template<class T>
vector<T> properDivisors(T input) {
    vector<T>retVal;
    for(T d = T()+1;d<input;d++) {
        if((double)input/(double)d == input/d)
            retVal.push_back(d);
    }
    return retVal;
}

template<class T>
T sumTypeOf(T input) {
    vector<T>divisors = properDivisors(T);
    return someEnum;
}
```

When compiling I get an error on the line:

```
    vector<T>divisors = properDivisors(T);
```

The error is:
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a value, not a type:

```
vector<T> divisors = properDivisors(input);
//                                  ^^^^^
```

Comment: Sorry for such a horrible question, I almost right away figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Hah! Sorry everyone, the problem was that I should have written properDivisors(input)

Stupid nub error... sorry...